# Java: Как происходит наследование членов класса?

Tags: java, наследование

Всем привет! Что вообще понимается под наследованием членов класса? Например, при создании объекта класса потомка, в памяти выделяется место под поля класса предка? И что происходит в зависимости от использования тех или иных модификаторов доступа в классе предке?

Comment: не прошло и 10 минут и уже дважды минусанули мой вопрос (: это конечно легче, чем простыми словами ответить мне

Comment: просто ваш вопрос не содержит конкретики. что именно вы хотите знать? сколько памяти и где выделяется? как количество выделяемой памяти зависит от модификаторов доступа? или вы сейчас интересуетесь наследованием в целом?

Comment: мне кажется, что отдельно наследование объяснять особого смысла нет. посмотрите это. я читал лекцию около года назад , здесь базовые принципы ооп и грасп. https://drive.google.com/open?id=1ARd-Hsq79mSSqhFl14m83-n7qCKcjiyN

Comment: с этим сложнее. эта запись просто завалялась у меня на гугл диске. дело в том, что я не очень часто читаю лекции в силу занятости. это либо корпоративные и они, разумеется, закрытые, либо на курсах в компьютерных школах. это в частности корпоративная лекция, онлай трансляции в этом случае ведутся только в пределах фирмы для ее офисов в разных городах.

Answer (score 1):

Отличные статьи на Метаните. Рекомендую к изучению.

https://metanit.com/java/tutorial/3.5.php

Answer (score 0):

Наследование — это процесс перенимания классом свойств (методов и полей) другого класса. С использованием в Java наследования информация становится управляемой в иерархическом порядке.

Класс, который наследует свойства другого класса, называется подклассом (производным классом, наследующим классом), а класс, свойства которого наследуются, известен как суперкласс (базовый класс, родительский класс)... http://proglang.su/java/inheritance

Comment: точно не скажу, но главное помнить, что private поля/методы - недоступны для пользования

Comment: посмотрел байт код - не наследует

Comment: да, если модификатор не private, то байт код показывает откуда она наследует поля/методы. А вот помеченные private - не показывает. Вывод: на уровне JVM работает также как гласит каноническое правило))

Comment: в чём код пишешь?

Comment: открываешь/пишешь нужный тебе класс в идеи: Viev -> Show Bytecode
и анализируешь, там интуитивно понятно.